# Uncaught ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk app-client-internals failed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Trying to make a simple todo app with NextJs. Whenever I try to use the

```js
       <button onClick={handleSubClick}
                className="w-[70%]"
                >
```

It triggers a reload, and the above error sometimes logs.

Rest of my code for the component`'use client';
import {useState} from 'react';

const AddPopup = () =>{

```
    const [subTasks, setSubTasks] = useState([]);

    const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);

    const handleSubClick = ()=>{
            const newSub = '1';
            const newArr = [...subTasks, newSub]
    try{
            setSubTasks([...newArr]);
    }catch(e){console.log(e);}
    }


    return(
            <div className={`bg-green-200 h-[50%] w-[50%] fixed flex`}>
            <form>
            <input
            placeholder="Add task"/>


            {
                    subTasks.map((sub) =>(
                            <input placeholder="subtask"/>
                    ))
            }

            <button onClick={handleSubClick}
            className="w-[70%]"
            >
            Add Subtask</button>

            </form>

            </div>


    );
```

}

export default AddPopup;    `

Comment: And no, deleting ./next folder doesnt work

Comment: try checking if `next dev` is not running more than once.